# How to check, if my product is already installed, when installing it?

Tags: plone

I want to execute parts of my code in an import-step, only if the product itself hasn't been installed, yet.

I tried with the 'listInstalledProduct's-method of the quickinstaller-tool.

However, this will return all installed prods but not my own one itself.

How can I check, if my product has already been installed in the site?

Comment: Those are at least 2 questions! :)

For the last one: you need to use the Extensions/install.py script like:

def install(portal, reinstall=False):
    ...

Comment: Right, I shortened my quest. IIRC, using the Extensions directory is deprececated/not recommended/old-style, isn't it? Good hint though, thx!

Comment: Yes, is deprecated, but as I know is the only way.

Comment: Tried your suggestion, still the code will be executed on a re-install, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the right hint of Anne Walther (a.k.a. 'awello'), I could find a solution:

```
from Products.CMFCore.utils import getToolByName
def myMethod(context):
    qi = getToolByName(context, 'portal_quickinstaller')

    prods = qi.listInstallableProducts(skipInstalled=False)

    for prod in prods:
        if (prod['id'] == 'your.productname') and (prod['status'] == 'new'):
        # further code...
```

For whatever reason and fortunately, the status of a product during a re-install will return 'uninstalled', not yet installed products come back with status 'new' and finally already installed prods of a site shout out loud and proud: 'installed'.

This way it is possible to distinguish a reinstall from an initial install.

Answer (score 0):

Doing the same in Plone 5 I managed Ida Ebkes code in:

```
from plone import api

def myMethod(context):

    portal = api.portal.get()
    qi = api.portal.get_tool('portal_quickinstaller')
    prods = qi.listInstallableProducts(skipInstalled=False)

    IsProductNameInstalled = len([k for k in prods if k['id']=='your.productname' and k['status']=='new']) == 0 and True or None

    if IsProductNameInstalled:
        # further code...
```